# Using the jquery cookies plugin

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, cookies, modal-dialog

How do I require it in my html?

the doc says use

```
<script src="/path/to/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
```

but what do I need to actually put for the "path" and the 'to'. Can't figure out what I need to do here. Hope someone can help! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With RoR: you must put the file `jquery.cookie.js` in the folder `vendor/assets/javascripts/`, then at the file `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` it must be called with:

```
//= require jquery.cookie
```

before

```
//= require_tree .
```

or any other require that needs jquery.cookie

You don't need a `script` tag.

Comment: If it is useful, please select the answer. The best way to say thank you!